# says table doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, yii, mamp

I have been using Yii with MAMP for the last week without problem. However, today, I set up a new project, created a database and tried to use Gii to create a new model but it's giving me a message "table name doesn't exist."

I have confirmed many times that such a table exists in PHP MY Admin. I also did a reinstall on MAMP and have the same problem

Can anyone see what the problem might be

[image: databse test1]

**This is my database**

This is my configuration in the Yii config file

```
'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;port:8889;dbname=test1',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: from your screenshots it shows you have a **database** called **test1** not a table. Your tables according to your screenshots are called **Department** and **Employee**

Comment: @martswite I changed that now. I uploaded the wrong image. Out of desperation I had entered different names to see. The problem is as I described it

Comment: @mjmitche ahh right well your table name should be Employee not employee

Comment: check that there should be no **space** before  and after `Employee` in your table name

Comment: @martswite I tried upper and lowercase Employee. no difference

Comment: Why is your port set to "8889"?  Mysql is usually 3306.

Comment: Ah, the mac port is 8889

Comment: Is the password really also `root`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit rusty, but ... case sensitivity? [Are column and table name case sensitive in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009005/is-field-and-table-name-case-sensitive-in-mysql)

Screenshot also states that no tables were found in the test1 database.

Comment: I just noticed the 0 table count also. Seems inconsistent with the view to the right of two tables. Been a very long time since I used phpMyAdmin

Comment: Just installed phpMyAdmin (albeit on Windows) and the part of the interface I see here is a bit different than what I was seeing. Could be an older version (I thought databases only displayed on the left).

Comment: @martswite @James Skemp I refreshed php my admin and now it lists the tables (where it said no tables) but it still has same problem

Comment: The 0 table count on the left is in a good old frame so it's not necessarily being updated each time the user makes an action on the right frame.

Comment: Ah yes, that's right - they do use frames. And I see you updated the case you're using. Have you tried cutting out the middle man and just creating a new test connection using the base functionality? That would help verify that it's not a connection issue.

Comment: There's no connection issue. Yii has that test built in and lets me know if no connect. I'm getting this error message. 10:25:21.298616 error system.db.CDbCommand 
CDbCommand::fetchAll() failed: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046
No database selected. The SQL statement executed was: SHOW COLUMNS FROM
`Employee`.
in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/demo/index.php (13)

Comment: At this point you're sadly beyond me. You should update your question with the information from your last comment on this answer; exact error returned is good to know.