# Calling Count column php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have query that `COUNT` the data based from user search condition in search.

My question is just simple although I don't know what the solution here:
I want to call the COUNT column, which I know it was just temporary column
I have `PHP` code like this:

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS SAMPLECOUNT FROM `subscribers` WHERE `country` = 'USA' ");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($count);
```

so by this code I  can echo the columns inside the `subscribers` by using this:

```
echo $row['country'];
*echo the count result here*
```

So maybe the output will be like this:

> USA: (the count result)

Comment: you'll want to look at [GROUP BY and Aggregate Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Ok, What is the output you getting, You stuck up there ?

Comment: Problem solved I can call by using this `echo $row['SAMPLECOUNT`];` 
now I know the alias can be used as column in php

Comment: I was just going to say that ^ and wondering why you weren't using that alias.

Comment: Man make that alias count! Or drop it

Comment: @Fred-ii- Maybe I got mental block, you can post the answer so I can accept it. hahaha

Comment: @JJ-SAMA It happens to all of us every once in a while (and eventually), believe me. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As requested*

Since you're using an alias `COUNT(*) AS SAMPLECOUNT` you pass it along in the `$row`'s array as

```
echo $row['SAMPLECOUNT'];
```

in order to show the row count's number.

Here are a few references:

- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

Sidenote: Aliases are case-sensitive on *NIX, but not so on Windows or Mac OSX”.

So `echo $row['samplecount']`; could fail if on *NIX.

---

However and quoting this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2009011/ on Stack:

*"On Unix, table names are case sensitive. On Windows, they are not. Fun, isn't it? Kinda like their respective file systems. Do you think it's a coincidence?*

*In other words, if you are planning on deploying on a Linux machine, better test your SQL against a Linux-based MySQL too, or be prepared for mysterious "table not found" errors at prod time. VMs are cheap these days.*

*Field names are case-insensitive regardless."*

Comment: You're wrong about nix/win. It's about default behavior only.

Comment: I see case sensitive.

Comment: @JJ-SAMA It could be an issue on some systems, yes.